# Increase precision of apache 2.2 log timestamp to include microseconds

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

A similar question was already asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405719/increase-precision-of-apache-log-to-include-milliseconds) 
but there was no helpful answer given and I think it fits better here.

I need to log the microseconds or milliseconds of the first response time.
I followed the format given in the documentation for apache 2.2 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html (I'm using apache 2.2.3) but it wont work. I changed the log format in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %{usec_frac}t \"%r\" %>s %b %D" test
```

The output I get is:

```
IPaddress - - [10/Oct/2015:19:47:46 +0200] usec_frac "GET /w/images/thumb/f/fa/Wikiquote-logo.svg/35px-Wikiquote-logo.svg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1931 86
```

So `usec_frac` is not resolved but it is listed in the documentation as a possible format for `%{format}t`. I'm using CentOS release 5.8 (Final) and I edited the httpd.conf with vi. What could be the problem here?

Comment: In the doc : "The extended strftime(3) tokens are available in 2.2.30 and later." I don't know what is the "extended" strtime, but it is maybe your option...

Answer (score 0):

As wrote in the official documentation you linked :

```
%{UNIT}T
```

> The time taken to serve the request, in a time unit given by UNIT.
>   Valid units are ms for milliseconds, us for microseconds, and s for
>   seconds. Using s gives the same result as %T without any format; using
>   us gives the same result as %D. Combining %T with a unit is available
>   in 2.2.30 and later.

Comment: @mchief90 is asking about timestamp logging not about the duration of the request. But the last part about 2.2.30 is correct and that answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to fix the problem you are having with Apache 2.2.3, but...

If nothing else works, look into the following (depending on how important this is to you)

1. Get the latest version of apache and compile it since it's not doing what it's supposed to and could be a bug. Maybe it will work, it couldn't hurt to try
2. If that doesn't work, edit the code and make it do what you want

I just tested on 2.4.10 and it works

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2015:16:37:50 -0400] 156545 "GET /cgi-bin/test.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 175 1206218
```